# Can't instantiate angular controller in karma unit tests

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, gulp, karma-jasmine

I'm facing some trouble with a generated project (by yoeman) and it's testing.

What I want is to build a fully automated testing environement. I use Gulp, Karma, Jasmine and angular-mocks.

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'controller.awesomeThings')
```

In my console after 'gulp test' it throws this error message. but this doesn't make any sense for me.

Look at my test spec:

```
'use strict';

describe('Controller: AboutCtrl', function() {

  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(function() {
    module('evoriApp');
  });

  var controller;
  var scope;

  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    controller = $controller('AboutCtrl', {
      '$scope': scope
    });
  }));

  it('should attach a list of awesomeThings to the scope', function() {
    console.log(controller);
    expect(controller.awesomeThings.length).toBe(3);
  });
});
```

And karma should have any file it needs (karma.conf.js):

```
files: [
      // bower:js
      'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
      'bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js',
      'bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
      'bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.js',
      'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
      'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
      'bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
      'bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.js',
      // endbower
      'app/scripts/**/*.js',
      'test/mock/**/*.js',
      'test/spec/**/*.js'
    ],
```

This is how the generated gulp method looks like:

```
gulp.task('test', ['start:server:test'], function () {
  var testToFiles = paths.testRequire.concat(paths.scripts, paths.mocks, paths.test);
  return gulp.src(testToFiles)
    .pipe($.karma({
      configFile: paths.karma,
      action: 'watch'
    }));
});
```

I don't know where the failure is. I checked all paths and rewrote the testfiles multiple times... But the error doesn't change.

Does anybody have an idea, what the error could be caused by?

Answer (score 1):

Ok guys, I got it.

I tried to run the test in the jasmine standalone environement to minimies the area where the error root is.

This is what my controller looks like:

```
angular.module('evoriApp')
  .controller('AboutCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];
    $scope.testVariable = 2;
  });
```

I rewrote the 'this.awesomeThings' to '$scope.awesomeThings' and didn't get it, that this is something different. Whatever...

This is the now running spec:

```
describe('Controller: AboutCtrl', function() {

  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(function() {
    module('evoriApp');
    console.log("1");
  });

  var controller;
  var scope;

  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    controller = $controller('AboutCtrl', {
      $scope: scope
    });
  }));

  it('sollte instanziert worden sein', function() {
    expect(controller).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('sollte ein Object "awesomeThings" besitzen', function() {
    expect(scope.awesomeThings).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('should attach a list of awesomeThings to the scope', function() {
    expect(scope.awesomeThings.length).toBe(3);
  });
});
```

What I learned: In a test you have to generate the scope, which you pass to the controller, by yourself and afterward you got to use the passed scope variable for $scope.variables.